# Is there a method in C# that converts just the characters with a special meaning in HTML and XML to entities?

Tags: c#, html, entities, html-encode

My programme generates an XML file with data from a database that contains special HTML/XML characters, so those need to be converted to entities.

I tried to use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` for that, which works but it does much more than I want.

Certain (but not all) non-ASCII characters such as the middle dot and superscript numbers are also converted even though they have no special meaning in HTML and XML.

I get for instance the string `a&amp;#183;ba&amp;#183;ĵur&amp;#183;o` instead of simply `a·ba·ĵur·o`.

As you see the circumflexed `"j"` is left as it is, but the dots are converted. This makes some data in the file difficult to read for humans;

I only want `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"` converted, nothing more.

Is there a method in C# that does that, or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SecurityElement.Escape("your HTML")`

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what i was looking for.